# Bit values into a keyword/value statement

Tags: sql

I've been given a table in SQL that has a flag field that contains multiple bit values

EG
Person_ID,
Flags

The values of the bits can be accessed as so:

```
WHEN BITAND (Flags, 1) <> 0 THEN 'Central Collection'
ELSE 'Delivery' AS 'Service Type'  

WHEN BITAND (Flags, 2) <> 0 THEN 'Given'
ELSE 'No Consent' AS 'Consent Status'
```

etc, there are a large number of these stored in the Flags field.

I want to write a single query that can display the values in Flags field as Keyword/Value EG

| Person_ID | Keyword | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Service Type | Delivery |
| 1 | Consent Status | Given |
| 2 | Service Type | Central Collection |
| 2 | Consent Status | No Consent |
| 3 | Service Type | Central Collection |
| 3 | Consent Status | Given |

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible:

```
SELECT Person_ID, Keyword, Value
FROM (
    SELECT Person_ID, 'Service_Type' AS Keyword, 
           WHEN BITAND (Flags, 1) <> 0 THEN 'Central Collection' ELSE 'Delivery' AS Value
    FROM yourtable

UNION 
    SELECT Person_ID, 'Consent Status' AS Keyword, 
           WHEN BITAND (Flags, 2) <> 0 THEN 'Given' ELSE 'No Consent' AS Value
    FROM yourtable
) t
ORDER BY Person_ID, Keyword DESC
```

The idea is to write two separate queries which provide you the two row-types, `UNION` them and secure the correct sort via the `ORDER BY`.

EDIT

If you have multiple flags, then you can implement a stored function that will return

```
SELECT Person_ID, TheKeyword,
       WHEN BITAND(Flags, TheNumber) <> 0 THEN TheTrueText ELSE TheFalseText AS Value
FROM yourtable;
```

Where the following are parameters:

- `TheKeyword`: The name of the keyword
- `TheNumber`: The mask you are checking the flags against
- `TheTrueText`: The text when `BITAND` returns true
- `TheFalseText` The text when `BITAND` returns false

Assuming that you named your function `f`, you can select f('Service_Type', 1, `CentralCollection`, 'Delivery', 'Value') and that generates one dimension of your query as a string. And then you can concatenate your calls of `f` with `union`s.

Alternatively, you can create a table where you store:

**my_settings(id, Keyword, MaskNumber, TrueText, FalseText)**

and then you can generate your stuff like:

```
SELECT Person_ID, Keyword,
       WHEN BITAND (Flags, MaskNumber) THEN TrueText ELSE FalseText END AS Value
FROM yourtable, my_settings
ORDER BY Person_ID, my_settings.id;
```

The above uses Descartes multiplication, which is in general frowned upon, but here you actually want to map everything with everything, so it should be good here. But of course, in order to be able to write a query as short as the one above, you will need to create your `my_settings` table and fill it with all the settings.

Comment: Is a UNION the only way? There are multiple (27) such bits in the flag field and my concern is that a statement with 27 UNIONs in it won't be great on performance

Comment: @Calid you can generate your script. Editing my answer

Comment: @Calid provided two alternatives in my edit to the answer. Please let me know if anything else is needed. If not, then you might consider accepting this as the correct answer.